# GKE: How to alert on memory request/allocatable ratio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a GKE cluster and I'd like to keep track of the ratio between the total memory requested and the total memory allocatable. I was able to create a chart in Google Cloud Monitoring using

```
metric.type="kubernetes.io/container/memory/request_bytes" resource.type="k8s_container"
```

and

```
metric.type="kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_bytes" resource.type="k8s_node"
```

both with `crossSeriesReducer` set to `REDUCE_SUM` in order to get the aggregate total across the cluster.

Then, when I tried to set up an alerting policy (using the cloud monitoring api) with the ratio of the two (following [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-json#json-ratio)), I get this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The numerator and denominator must have the same resource type.
```

It doesn't like that the first metric is a `k8s_container` and the second metric is a `k8s_node` Are there different metrics I can use or some sort of workaround in order to alert on memory request/allocatable ratio in Google Cloud Monitoring?

EDIT:

Here is the full request and response

```
$ gcloud alpha monitoring policies create --policy-from-file=policy.json
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The numerator and denominator must have the same resource type.

$ cat policy.json
{
    "displayName": "Cluster Memory",
    "enabled": true,
    "combiner": "OR",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "displayName": "Ratio: Memory Requests / Memory Allocatable",
            "conditionThreshold": {
                 "filter": "metric.type=\"kubernetes.io/container/memory/request_bytes\" resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
                 "aggregations": [
                    {
                        "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
                        "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
                        "groupByFields": [
                        ],
                        "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
                    }
                ],
                "denominatorFilter": "metric.type=\"kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_bytes\" resource.type=\"k8s_node\"",
                "denominatorAggregations": [
                   {
                      "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
                      "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
                      "groupByFields": [
                       ],
                      "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN",
                    }
                ],
                "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
                "thresholdValue": 0.8,
                "duration": "60s",
                "trigger": {
                    "count": 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If it's possible please edit your post and show the request as well as returning response code.

Comment: @DawidKruk edited. I used the gcloud cli so I don't see the API response code, but I'm guessing it's a 4xx code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The numerator and denominator must have the same resource type.
```

Following official documentation:

> **groupByFields[] - parameter**
>
> The set of fields to preserve when `crossSeriesReducer` is specified. The `groupByFields` determine how the time series are partitioned into subsets prior to applying the aggregation operation. Each subset contains time series that have the same value for each of the grouping fields. Each individual time series is a member of exactly one subset. The `crossSeriesReducer` is applied to each subset of time series. **It is not possible to reduce across different resource types, so this field implicitly contains `resource.type`**. Fields not specified in `groupByFields` are aggregated away. If `groupByFields` is not specified and all the time series have the same resource type, then the time series are aggregated into a single output time series. If `crossSeriesReducer` is not defined, this field is ignored.
>
> --  *[Cloud.google.com: Monitoring: projects.alertPolicies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies)*

Please take specific look on part:

> **It is not possible to reduce across different resource types, so this field implicitly contains `resource.type`**.

**Above error shows when you try to create a policy with a different resource types.**

Metrics shown below have `Resource type` of:

- `kubernetes.io/container/memory/request_bytes` - `k8s_container`
- `kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_bytes` - `k8s_node`

You can check the `Resource type` by looking at the metric in the `GCP Monitoring`:

[image: Container]

[image: Node]

As a workaround you could try to create an alert policy which will alert you when allocatable utilization of memory is above 85%. It will indirectly tell you that requested memory is high enough to trigger an alarm.

Example below with YAML:

```yaml
combiner: OR
conditions:
- conditionThreshold:
    aggregations:
    - alignmentPeriod: 60s
      crossSeriesReducer: REDUCE_SUM
      groupByFields:
      - resource.label.cluster_name
      perSeriesAligner: ALIGN_MEAN
    comparison: COMPARISON_GT
    duration: 60s
    filter: metric.type="kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_utilization" resource.type="k8s_node"
      resource.label."cluster_name"="GKE-CLUSTER-NAME"
    thresholdValue: 0.85
    trigger:
      count: 1
  displayName: Memory allocatable utilization for GKE-CLUSTER-NAME by label.cluster_name
    [SUM]
  name: projects/XX-YY-ZZ/alertPolicies/AAA/conditions/BBB
creationRecord:
  mutateTime: '2020-03-31T08:29:21.443831070Z'
  mutatedBy: XXX@YYY.com
displayName: alerting-policy-when-allocatable-memory-is-above-85
enabled: true
mutationRecord:
  mutateTime: '2020-03-31T08:29:21.443831070Z'
  mutatedBy: XXX@YYY.com
name: projects/XX-YY-ZZ/alertPolicies/
```

Example with `GCP Monitoring web access`:

[image: GCP Monitoring metric web]

Please let me know if you have any questions in that.

### EDIT:

To properly create alert policies which will show relevant data you need to take a lot of factors into consideration like:

- type of workload
- amount of nodes and node pools
- node affinity (for example: spawn certain type of workload on GPU nodes)
- etc

For more advanced alert policy which will take into consideration the allocatable memory **per node pool** you can do something like that:

```yaml
combiner: OR
conditions:
- conditionThreshold:
    aggregations:
    - alignmentPeriod: 60s
      crossSeriesReducer: REDUCE_SUM
      groupByFields:
      - metadata.user_labels."cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool"
      perSeriesAligner: ALIGN_MEAN
    comparison: COMPARISON_GT
    duration: 60s
    filter: metric.type="kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_utilization" resource.type="k8s_node"
      resource.label."cluster_name"="CLUSTER_NAME"
    thresholdValue: 0.85
    trigger:
      count: 1
  displayName: Memory allocatable utilization (filtered) (grouped) [SUM]
creationRecord:
  mutateTime: '2020-03-31T18:03:20.325259198Z'
  mutatedBy: XXX@YYY.ZZZ
displayName: allocatable-memory-per-node-pool-above-85
enabled: true
mutationRecord:
  mutateTime: '2020-03-31T18:18:57.169590414Z'
  mutatedBy: XXX@YYY.ZZZ
```

Please be aware that there is a bug: [Groups.google.com: Google Stackdriver discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-stackdriver-discussion/apM-MJwTj7Q) and the only possibility to create above alert policy is with command line.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer! The only problem with the workaround using allocatable utilization is that it may be hard to aggregate that metric among many nodes with all different allocatable memory amounts. Can you think of any other possible workarounds?

Comment: @JesseShieh please take a look at my edited answer. I added more advanced alert policy which will work with node pools. The allocatable memory metric can be used per each node too. Word about `allocatable utilization` metric: `The fraction of the allocatable memory that is currently in use on the instance. This value cannot exceed 1 as usage cannot exceed allocatable memory bytes.` It will always take into consideration amount of memory.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the awesome answer. It looks like this will basically alert anytime any node pool is highly utilized (over 85%), but is there a way to alert when the entire cluster is utilized over 85%? For example, let's say there are 32 4GB machines that are all 100% utilized, but there is a single 128GB machine that is 0% utilized. The entire cluster is 50% utilized so an alert should not fire.

Comment: It shouldn't fire as the workload should be spawned on 1x128GB machine too. If it's not, there is probably a reason for that (for example `node Affinity`). Creating this alert policies should include that. Also, you could always check the utilization per node.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted, but I would still love to have a way to see the ratio of total requested to total allocatable as one number across the entire cluster someday.